# Создание связанной модели в Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, activerecord

Здравствуйте.

Все ни как не могу разобраться. Как создать связанную модель в Yii2.

Задача в том, что есть две модели ActiveRecord.

model1 содержит поля [id, A, B]
model2 содержит поля [id, C, model1_id].

Т.е. model2 должна в поле [model1_id] вводить id model1.

Правильно ли будет в model2 прописать?

```
public function getCustomer()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Model1::className(), ['model1_model_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Я написал так, но model1_id в Бд не записывает.
В чем ошибка, как нужно будет правильно сделать?

В бд связь таблиц не делал.

Заранее спасибо. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрим в [документацию](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#declaring-relations) и видим следующий пример:

```
return $this->hasOne(Customer::className(), ['id' => 'customer_id']);
```

То есть вам нужно поменять местами поля и опустить `_model_`:

```
return $this->hasOne(Model1::className(), ['id' => 'model1_id']);
```

Comment: так. Получается мы создали связь. Но она в бд сохраняться не будет?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: То, что при создание новой записи, когда мы зададим поля A B C, поле model1_id заполнится автоматически? 
Вот будет новая запись. 
id - 7 A - 10 B -11  //model1
id-2 C -14 model1_id - будет ли задана автоматически число 7? //model2

Вроде постарался объяснить понятно.

Comment: Конечно нет. При создании записи в модель `Model2` вы должны явно указать в поле `model1_id` ID записи из модели `Model1`.

Comment: Все. Понял. Спасибо. )